# Regex, php.. Remove any mathing strings from a source

Tags: php, regex, template-engine

I have a php template engine that i've been building. But i'am not that strong in regex. 
I need to find any mathcing string looking like this. Keep in mind this is a simple template engine

Strings looks like this: {$string}
Now the string is only an alias of a actual php variabel extrateced from an array.

Thanks :) 


EDIT:
Does any one have a good read for understanding regex, you guys make it look easy :P

Comment: smarty? Would `{\$\w+}` do it?

Comment: What are you considering valid characters to appear in the string label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get more elaborate and cover exactly what is allowed as a PHP variable name, you could try this:

```
\{\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this.  Looks like I missed the backslash on both curlybraces.

Answer (score 0):

```
\{\$.*\}
```

I think that should do it.

Actually:

```
\{\$[A-Za-z]+[^\}]*\}
```

to match one or more alphabet characters (which a php variable has to start with), and zero or more characters after that.

The `[^\}]` will make sure it only finds one at set at a time.

Comment: @Damp Just updated my answer better, actually, if you want to see what could make that better.

Comment: Is the OP wants to do capture (which he probably will) `{(.*)}` will not work as it will match this `'{$a}{$b}'` and capture `'$a}{$b'` because of regexp greediness. All I did was change your `.*` to `.*?` to prevent greedy behavior